# Add new Custom T4 template in Add New Controller Dialog under Scaffold options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, t4scaffolding

I want to implement new T4 templates which should appear under Scaffold options in Add New Controller Dialog.

I have tried adding a new View tt template.I was able to add it.
I need a reference where I can get basic information on how to create a new Controller template  rather than modifying existing one.

Thanks
Patil

Comment: Despite articles like [this by Scott Hanselman on creating custom templates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx), I also am having trouble with .t4 templates placed locally inside of CodeTemplates/MvcView/ showing up in the Add New View Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at MVCScaffolding?  http://nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding/

You can easily override the controller t4 template using MVCScaffolding: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/